# Writing a list of data values to a .dat file to plot in GNUplot (in C)

Tags: c, file, gnuplot

Hiya, I have written two different methods to numerically differentiate a function and I am looking for a way to compare them.  I have installed GNUPlot and would like to make a file (e.g. approximations.dat) for it to plot.  At the moment my programn prints a series of columns with x-coordinate, approximation 1, approximation 2 and actual value like this:

```
x-coord      approx 1      approx 2      actual  
x-coord      approx 1      approx 2      actual  
x-coord      approx 1      approx 2      actual  
x-coord      approx 1      approx 2      actual  
 ...            ...           ...          ...
```

Is there a way for me to make this into a file which can be input easily into GUPlot?  Many thanks.

Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already a format well suited for gnuplot.  Look up `help plot using` from the gnuplot prompt.

In order to get this into a file, you can either pipe the standard output from your program (e.g. in Unix-like systems with `yourprog > file.dat`), or use the C function `fprintf` (with `fopen` and `fclose`).

Comment: In order to 'pipe' it in do i need to have my program returning a set of arrays or just having the columns printed out as is currently the case?

Comment: @Jack Medley:  Your "just printing out" is the same as "outputting on standard output stream".  Pipes operate on streams, so "just printing out" is right.

Comment: Cool, ive starting implementing the fprintf approach but I'll have a crack at that after for good measure!

Comment: I had a go at this 'piping' approach with this code: http://pastebin.com/pjrQLNpk
then in terminal used:
gcc -lm mycode.c > test.dat
But that printed a blank file.  I think we may talking at crossed purposes :s

Comment: @Jack Medley:  Piping has nothing to do with the compilation.  You can pipe any program output.  Simply run your program with the pipe: `myprog > file.dat`.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial should help you http://www.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html

Comment: Yeah, i found this a while ago.  My problem is mainly getting the data into the .dat file.  I can do the rest. Cheers